# Github - forking a private repository

Tags: github

I have access to a private repository. If I fork the private repository what is the access the owner of the original repository or the admin of the original repository have to my forked repository? How do these rules change if I fork a public repository?

Answer (score 3):

When forking a private repository, all the collaborators will be copied automatically, meaning the owner will have push rights to your fork. You can later remove collaborators from the repository settings page.

When forking a public repository collaborators are not copied so you'll be the only one with push rights.

Comment: If you fork a private repository, then remove the owner of the upstream repository from the list of collaborators on your fork, can that owner still see changes that you commit to your fork? I understand that in doing this you remove their push rights, but what about get?